# Error installing mysql-client my_config.h not found Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, pip

Yes i know its asked several times but majority of them havent helped me , so i have similar issue about when i tried to install `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.10`
it gives :

```
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,3,10,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.10 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/mert/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-mVh3j5tK/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:29:10: fatal error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
       29 | #include "my_config.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/mert/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-mVh3j5tK/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vpcd78dz/mysqlclient_02860d9ff5b24c97abfc0dd675c9003c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vpcd78dz/mysqlclient_02860d9ff5b24c97abfc0dd675c9003c/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-s0tuhkac/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/mert/.local/share/virtualenvs/api-mVh3j5tK/include/site/python3.6/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

If i try to put that file inside `usr/include/mysql` then it gives ieeefp.h not found error.